# How to format Double with dot?

Tags: java, string, format, double

How do I format a Double with `String.format` to String with a dot between the integer and decimal part?

```
String s = String.format("%.2f", price);
```

The above formats only with a comma: ",".

Answer (score 146, accepted):

`String.format(String, Object ...)` is using your JVM's default locale. You can use whatever locale using `String.format(Locale, String, Object ...)` or [`java.util.Formatter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Formatter.html) directly.

```
String s = String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", price);
```

or

```
String s = new Formatter(Locale.US).format("%.2f", price);
```

or

```
// do this at application startup, e.g. in your main() method
Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);

// now you can use String.format(..) as you did before
String s = String.format("%.2f", price);
```

or

```
// set locale using system properties at JVM startup
java -Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US ...
```

Comment: Adding to the list:    
(new DecimalFormat("0.##", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US))).format(price);

Comment: Note that the 2nd approach (Formatter.format) returns the Formatter itself. One needs to instantize the Formatter with a object where to put the output to for it to work (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-)

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [post](https://edivad.wordpress.com/2008/03/21/java-formatting-a-number-with-right-dots-and-commas/) you can do it like this and it works for me on Android 7.0

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.ITALY));
System.out.println(df.format(yourNumber)); //will output 123.456,78
```

This way you have dot and comma based on your `Locale`

*Answer edited and fixed thanks to Kevin van Mierlo comment*

Comment: There's a problem here: if the numer is **0.0** , the result is **,00**, instead of **0,00** : how can be fixed? ps: there's a typo in `df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(` , misses un L `Symbos`

Comment: @Leviand you are right, I don't know why that happens. I would suggest to create a kotlin extension and set a condition when number is 0

Comment: # means possible number, but left away if it's not there. Hence 0 would result in this. To fix this use "#,##0.00". See the third 0. That means that number will always be filled.

Comment: @KevinvanMierlo  I tested it and you're right, I will edit the answer. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

If it works the same as in PHP and C#, you might need to set your locale somehow. Might find something more about that in the [Java Internationalization FAQ](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/basic/intl/faq.jsp#core-locale).