# How to set particular number of Digits in double/float primitive type in java?

Tags: java, floating-point, decimal, precision

I want a particular number of digits in double/float primitive type. Is there any way to do this?

For example: (fixed to 6 digits)

1. If we have 12.666666667 gives output as 12.6667
2. If we have 5.6666666667 gives output as 5.66667
3. However, if we have 9.00000000 gives output as only 9.*

For, more clear understanding, I have attached an image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXGgB.jpg)

How to replicate the same output that I got from below mentioned code in java:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  float num = 9.34333666666663;
  float num2 = 12.0000000
  cout << num;
  cout << num2;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:-

```
9.34334
12
```

Comment: So what did you try?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format Double with dot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182451/how-to-format-double-with-dot)

Answer (score 0):

Two things to consider. One is if you need an exact precision, since floating point arithmetic might not give you that. See the `BigDecimal` class for more information. The other is what you're trying to do: display a number with a certain number of decimal places. You can accomplish this with `String.format`. For example

```
double num = 5.666666666;
String formatted = String.format("%.5f", num);
```

And

```
System.out.println(formatted)
```

Will output

```
5.66667
```

Comment: But What if we have 12.6666667 ?
Then, the above code will give output as 12.66667 but Output requires as 12.6667(total 6 digits only).

And in case of 9.00000000 require only 9 as output.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class rounding {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double num = 23.122345899;
        double rounded = Math.round(num * 1000000) / 1000000.0;
        System.out.println(rounded);
    }
}
```